# jquery colors, RGB to HSL and back

Tags: jquery, colors

I'm using [jquery colors](https://github.com/Enideo/jquery-colors) to transform a color from hex to hsl, modify it's hue by adding a number from 0 to 360 to it, then doing a mod 360 to get the new hue value that i'm actually interested in obtaining

Problem is I can't figure out how to transform it back to RGB correctly

Given the following example (you can test it on [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/andrei4002/uEUJq/5/)), why does `hslAfter` have a different value than `hsl`?

From what I can see, I'm just transforming `originalColor` which is in HEX, to a HSL array of values, then trying to make a string from it, in `hslAfter`.

```
function testHue() {
    var originalColor = $.colors($("#originalColor").val());

    var hsl = $.colors(originalColor).model('HSL').get();
    var hslAfter = $.colors(hsl).toString('hsl');
    var hex = $.colors(hsl).toString('hex');
}
```

shouldn't `hslAfter` have the same values as `hsl`? (I'm not even mentioning the new hex value here, which of course in turn, should be the same as the original hex color)

Am I missing something here (anyway to fix this)?

Comment: I'm confused by your fiddle... if I put in `#ffffff`, are we expecting the last item to be `#ffffff`?

Comment: I am too.  But your question starts out by talking about shifting the hue.

Comment: I am explaining the algorithm that I thought of using (converting to hsl, modifying hue, go back to rgb) and give an obvious example of what my problem is (if I were to actually shift a color in the fiddle, I wouldn't see it that obvious). Maybe there's something wrong in how I do it, maybe there's another (better) way of doing it (just putting all the facts in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just missed some parameters [as per the documentation](http://enideo.com/code/jquery-colors-plugin/)...

```
$.colors( colorInput, [formatName], [modelName] )
```

> Creates a color based on the arguments. Returns the color object.
>
> **colorInput** A string or array representing a color
>
> **formatName** The name of the format of the color
>
> **modelName** The name of the color model of the color

Here's a DEMO, where the HEX output is now the same as the HEX input...

**http://jsfiddle.net/uEUJq/9/**

Comment: have you tried putting #FF0000 as the source color? it transforms it to #000000 and I have no idea why

Comment: @AndreiS, That is odd... it does the same with `00FF00` and then with `0000FF` it ends up being `FFFFFF`... other combinations like `#FF0100` work fine.  I'd say this has to be a bug in the plugin and the developer should be notified of this thread along with the JSFiddles.

Comment: @ayjay, [the posted demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uEUJq/9/) is still working the same as the day it was created.

Comment: @Sparky, I'm getting this error on the console log: `Uncaught TypeError: $.colors is not a function`

Comment: @ayjay, I am getting no console errors on that jsFiddle.  Sounds like your browser is having a problem loading the plugin.

Comment: maybe so. I'm on a new mac book pro (yosemite) with the latest chrome.  Oh well. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jscolor.js](http://jscolor.com/release/2.0/jscolor-2.0.4/jscolor.js) from [jscolor.com](http://jscolor.com/). They have many [examples](http://jscolor.com/examples/).

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEUJq/163/) for my example.

```js
function testHue() {
    var originalColor = $.colors($("#originalColor").val());
    
    var rgb = $.colors(originalColor).model('RGB').get();
    var hsl = $.colors(originalColor).model('HSL').get();
    var hslAfter = $.colors(hsl,'array3Normalized', 'HSL').toString('hsl');
    var hex = $.colors(hsl,'array3Normalized', 'HSL').toString('hex');
  
    $("#rgbColor").html("<b>rgb: </b>" + rgb);
    $("#hslColor").html("<b>hsl: </b>" + hsl);
    $("#hslAfter").html("<b>hsl.toString('hsl'):</b> " + hslAfter);
    $("#hexColor").html("<b>hsl.toString('hex'): </b>" + hex);    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://http://jscolor.com/release/2.0/jscolor-2.0.4/jscolor.js"></script>

<div style="width:500px; margin:5px;">
    <div id="rgbColor"><b>rfb: </b></div>
    <div id="hslColor"><b>hsl: </b></div>
    <div id="hslAfter"><b>hsl.toString('hsl'):</b></div>
    <div id="hexColor"><b>hsl.toString('hex'): </b></div>
    
<br/>

<input type="text" id="originalColor" 
class="jscolor {hash:true}" 
onchange="testHue();"
value="ab2567" />
</div>
```